Code gets stucked at Archive.finalize() while finalizing the archive for the archiver pacakge of node js
I am trying to archive the keys of a folder of aws s3 i am using archiver pacakge for that
https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver
when the code goes to await archive.finalize();
line it' get stucked there it only works when the folder as keys less than 1 mb i guess coz i tried
compressing a folder which contains a 1.62 mb jpg  and it get stucked there
async function createsZipOrGzip(
  client: S3ExtendedClient,
  keys: string[],
  folderCompressionMode: FolderCompressionMode,
  filePath: string
) {
  try {
    client.logger.info(`createsZipOrGzip function started`);
    client.logger.debug(
      `input got in createsZipOrGzip method is keys:${JSON.stringify(
        keys
      )} filePath: ${filePath} folderCompressionMode:${folderCompressionMode}`
    );
    const compresionMode =
      folderCompressionMode === FolderCompressionMode.ZIP ? "zip" : "tar";
    const archive = archiver(compresionMode, {
      zlib: { level: 1 }, // Set compression level
    });

    // Iterate through each object key
    client.logger.info("getting object from the keys");
    for (const key of keys) {
      // Get the object from S3
      const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: client.bucket,
        Key: key,
      });

      client.logger.info("getting object the keys", key);

      const response = await client.s3client.send(command);
      // Append the file to the zip archive
       archive.append(response.Body, { name: key });

      client.logger.info("appended  the key", key);
    }

    await archive.finalize();

    client.logger.debug(`worked from here?`);

    if (filePath.endsWith("/")) filePath = filePath.slice(0, -1);

    if (folderCompressionMode === FolderCompressionMode.GZIP) {
      const gzip = zlib.createGzip();
      // compressing the tar to gzip as gzip can't alone compress multiple files
      archive.pipe(gzip);
      return {
        archive: gzip,
        key: filePath !== "" ? `${filePath}.tgz` : "root.tgz",
      };
    }

    client.logger.info("compressed  successfully function ended");

    return {
      archive,
      key:
        filePath !== ""
          ? `${filePath}.${compresionMode}`
          : `root.${compresionMode}`,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
}


     const streamZipOrTar = await createsZipOrGzip(
        client,
        keys,
        folderMode,
        filePath
      );


i calls it like this and i get stucked  client.logger.debug(worked from here?); this log doesn't logs so the issue is with the await archive.finaliz();
i had tried to download small files but still it get stucks. there
if i convert the stream of a single file without covnerting it to a archive it works fine
